# Appium exited before timeout error on every second execution in WDIO

Tags: automated-tests, appium, android-testing, webdriver-io, android-uiautomator

I am running a test suite using WebDriverIO and Appium to automate Android app testing. My test suite runs successfully on the first execution, but on the second execution, I am getting an "Appium exited before timeout" error. The third execution runs well, but the fourth execution again gives the same error.

Here are my dev dependencies on package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/appium-service": "^8.8.8",
        "@wdio/cli": "^8.8.8",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.8.8",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.8.7",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.8.7",
        "appium": "^2.0.0-beta.66",
        "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^2.23.0"
    },
```

Here are my capabilities from wdio.const.js:

```
capabilities: [
    {
      platformName: 'Android',
      'appium:platformVersion': '13.0',
      'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64',
      'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
      'appium:app': `${join(
        process.cwd(),
        './app/android/ApiDemos-debug.apk'
      )}`,
    },
  ],
```

And here is complete error:

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-05-04T13:02:35.362Z

2023-05-04T13:02:35.474Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2023-05-04T13:02:54.654Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/asus/VS%20Projects/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/appium-service/build/launcher.js:116:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Continue...
2023-05-04T13:02:54.663Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-05-04T13:02:54.666Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2023-05-04T13:02:59.905Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in Android - file:///C:/Users/asus/VS%20Projects/webdriverio-appium-v8/test/specs/android-findElemets.spec.js
[0-0] 2023-05-04T13:03:00.736Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol     
[0-0] 2023-05-04T13:03:01.511Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/session
[0-0] 2023-05-04T13:03:01.512Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:platformVersion': '13.0',
[0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\asus\\VS Projects\\webdriverio-appium-v8\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:platformVersion': '13.0',
[0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': 'C:\\Users\\asus\\VS Projects\\webdriverio-appium-v8\\app\\android\\ApiDemos-debug.apk'
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2023-05-04T13:03:04.831Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: read ECONNRESET
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/asus/VS%20Projects/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:789:107)
[0-0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:539:35)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
[0-0]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
[0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
[0-0]     at Runner.run (file:///C:/Users/asus/VS%20Projects/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:77:19)
[0-0] FAILED in Android - file:///C:/Users/asus/VS%20Projects/webdriverio-appium-v8/test/specs/android-findElemets.spec.js
2023-05-04T13:03:04.990Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2023-05-04T13:03:04.993Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:29

2023-05-04T13:03:04.996Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2023-05-04T13:03:05.258Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2023-05-04T13:03:05.260Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error every other time I run the test suite. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

I deleted and reinstalled the node_modules and package-lock.json files. But It didn't work. I would also like to point out that I am getting the same an error when I use my locally installed appium package.